# Appendix in Word document is being subordinated to a heading

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

I have formatted an appendix using Word's built-in formats but for some reason the appendix is being subordinated to the regular headings. So, for example, if I trying to insert a cross reference, I get this:

[image]

In this case the Appendix A should be at the top level, not subordinated to Section 11.

I tried adding a section break, but that made no difference, it only changed the page numbers. How can I get the Appendix to the top level?

Comment: Could you show us how does this really affect the appearance of Appendix A within your document, regardless of what its level is subordinate to? It looks normal if Appendix A's style is Heading 4 or 5. But if you are referring to Table of Contents, levels can be upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the set up for the "multilevel" list numbering for the Appendix styles in your document.  From your screenshot, I'd suspect that they've been set up on the same list numbering style as your main clause numbering.

If you want them to show up with Appendix A back at the main level, you need to have two separate liststyles - one for the clause numbering (so that would be your 1., 1.1, and any other lower levels eg (a), (i) etc), and then create a separate liststyle for your Appendix numbering.

In the second liststyle, you would have Appendix A's style attached to level 1, A.1's style attached to level 2, and A.1.1's style attached to level 3 etc (currently your Appendix A style is attached to a lower level on the numbering scheme so that's why it appears in the cross-reference dialog box indented - it reflects the attached numbering level).